# jQuery moving list items between two select tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two select elements on html. The first one has some options/items and when I double click one of the options it will be removed from the first select and appended to the second select. Then if I double click an option on the second select the option will be moved back to the first list.

For example:

```
<select  multiple="multiple" id="list1">

    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="apricot">apricot</option>
    <option value="lemon">lemon</option>

</select>

<select  multiple="multiple" id="list2">
</select>
```

jQuery part is  as the following

```
    $(function () {

        $("#list1 option").dblclick(function () {

            $("#list1 option:selected").remove().appendTo("#list2");

        });


        $("#list2 option").dblclick(function () {
            $("#list2 option:selected").remove().appendTo("#list1");

        });

    });
```

I can move an option in "list1" into "list2" but cannot move back it to "list1" from "list2".

```js
$(function () {

            $("#list1 option").dblclick(function () {

                $("#list1 option:selected").remove().appendTo("#list2");

            });


            $("#list2 option").dblclick(function () {
                $("#list2 option:selected").remove().appendTo("#list1");

            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  multiple="multiple" id="list1">
    
        <option value="banana">banana</option>
        <option value="orange">orange</option>
        <option value="apricot">apricot</option>
        <option value="lemon">lemon</option>

    </select>
    
    <select  multiple="multiple" id="list2">
    </select>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title. It should be a clear, specific question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: when an `element` gets removed from `list1` what happens to it's original `listener` and when you add it to `list2` does it get a `listener` or just `the originals of `list2` get a `listener` in this code?

Comment: @MeBottleOScrumpy I think you have the found the problem but I do not have enoguh information about `listeners`, probably your question's answer is no.

Comment: @ths the minimal reproducible example added.

Comment: after adding `console.log`, i found out that apparently when element from `list1` gets added to `list2` some how does not a get a `double click` listener.

Comment: @zkanoca I think you should clone, remove and then append the cloned element to the appropriate `select` element. Also, I advise you to use event delegation here because you're working with dynamically added elements.

Comment: You need to use event delegation because you're changing the selector of the elements dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the `dblcick` event will trigger for dynamicly moved elements, remove the id from the selector and make it a single function that will check which select has been clicked, and will move it to the other

```js
$("option").dblclick(function () {
    const clickedElement = event.target;
    const appendToId = (event.target.parentElement.id === 'list1') ? 'list2' : 'list1';

    clickedElement.remove();
    $(clickedElement).appendTo('#' + appendToId);
});
```

```css
select { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select  multiple="multiple" id="list1">
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="apricot">apricot</option>
    <option value="lemon">lemon</option>
</select>

<select  multiple="multiple" id="list2">
</select>
```

Comment: Remove is not necessarily needed if append is used:

$('#' + appendToId).append(clickedElement);